# How to send a notification to another PC?

Tags: c, windows

Is there a way i can send a notification/message to another PC in C/C++? I think something like net send, but i don't know if there is another way to send a notification/message. I created an application which will run on every PC, and i want, that if my application has finished it should send a notification to my PC, that it has finished running. I don't know if there is a solution for my question, but if yes, could someone tell me, how to do that?

Thanks,

kampi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something like "NET SEND" use mailslots!

Here more info on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365576.aspx

Comment: Hi! Thank you all for your ideas, but i think mailslot is the closest what i want.

Answer (score 1):

How about using sockets?

http://www.alhem.net/Sockets/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Start by learning about WCF.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx

We ended up building a system for alerting all of our retail locations of emergency situations by building a service that opens up a TCP channel using .NET Remoting.  It just sits there and listens for notifications.  Our command center has a program that can send out notifications to this service.  The service is responsible for displaying the message.

The code is proprietary, so I can't share it, but that's the general idea.  Remoting has been rolled into WCF, which is why I started by suggesting learning that.

It has been working very well for us for many years, and works just fine on newer versions of Windows (unlike Net Send) and it's faster than Net Send.

**Edit - added**

I hadn't heard of this until now but you could also look into msg.exe.  it looks easier.

http://www.appscout.com/2009/03/vistas_msgexe_replaces_net_sen.php

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use net send, how about just creating a date-stamped temp file of some sort that your other PC looks for?

Answer (score 0):

Net Send is an option, but I think it will annoy the crap out of you, as it sends console toast to your computer, which pops up in front of the tasks you are working on. Personally, I would find that incredibly annoying.

If you created the application, you have the ability to include notication code. As an example, you can set up a service on your box and write the code to contact that service. On a windows machine, this can be a WCF service. You can also wrap this in a windows service if you want to fire up non-annoying toast.

I am not sure how to set up C to access a service, so another option might be to drop something in a folder and have a file watcher tell you. A bit kludgy, of course.

Comment: Net Send is not available in Vista or Win7.  XP was the last OS to support it.  Your WCF suggestion is really the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Make your application a [Growl client](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/)